# trouble with irssi and cifs

Tags: filesystems, permissions, mount, gentoo, irssi

I'm having trouble getting irssi, the irc client, to write to a mounted cifs share. I have the uid, and gid set to my user as well as setting the permissions on the share to being very permissive. When I tried to download a file in irssi I get an error that the file can't be created, and that the text file is busy.

Here is the command I'm mounting the drive with (as root for my generic user)

```
mount -t cifs -v -o username=user,password=pass,uid=1001,gid=1001,dir_mode=0777 \
    //server/myshare /mnt/cloud
```

Anyone have a clue what might be the issue? I'm running 2.6.34-gentoo.

Comment: Is your user allowed to write to `/mnt/cloud` normally? Can you post the specific error output of irrsi?

Comment: 01:32 DCC can't create file /mnt/cloud/*filename*: Text file busy.  

As for the folder, yes the user can edit files, create files and folders, delete. I even wrote a script in php executing a command on the commmand line and it was also able to edit the folder.

Comment: Can't answer this question, but some pointers: [Here's what `irssi` does to save a received file](http://svn.irssi.org/repos/irssi/trunk/src/irc/dcc/dcc-get.c) (see `void sig_dccget_connected`), and [here's someone's hints regarding the `ETXTBSY`](http://www.cs.rug.nl/~jurjen/ApprenticesNotes/ch29s03.html).  Maybe you can try to approximate what `irssi` does via command line to corner the issue?

Answer (score 4):

irssi normally won't save DCC downloads outside of a jail it imposes.  On my system, that's my home directory.  Try this:

```
/set dcc_download_path /mnt/cloud
```

Which will allow dcc to save files to anything under `/mnt/cloud`, but nowhere else.

**NOTE:** Be very careful that there is only one space after `dcc_download_path` and no "=" sign. Even multiple spaces will  be taken as part of the path.

Comment: I've actually been using the /set dcc_download_path command. It didn't help.

Comment: `and no "=" sign` is the key